# Subdivision surface doesn't show vertex

Tags: subdivision-surface

I'm learning the sculpting course from CG boost and I had a weird issue. I saw in the tutorial Zach created a cube and merged it into a point, then he extruded the point to make a line. After that he added a subdivision surface modifier to add more points. The weird thing is, when I did the same thing, my spline didn't show the subdivided points like in the tutorial. Do you know why it's different? Thanks[image][image]

Comment: Are you talking about right click > Subdivide? Make sure that you've selected the 2 vertices of your edge, and not only one vertex, it may be your problem here. If you're talking about a Subdivision Surface modifier, you need to apply it to create the additional vertices.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using the subdivision surface modifier. It works for sure after I apply the modifier. The thing is in the tutorial when you change the levels viewport, you can see the points increasing in the viewport. I can't see the realtime changing while tweaking the numbers. But yes subdivide might be a better way, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you need to apply the modifier to generate the new vertices. The number of Levels on the modifier will determine the number of 'cuts' or vertices in this case.

[image]

Switch back to Object mode and Apply the modifier and then you will see your new vertices if you return to Edit mode.

[image]

A slightly better way to do this is to create your line with two points. In Edit mode select both vertices then right click the line and choose Subdivide from the right click menu. A small menu will appear in the lower left of your viewport. Expand this and set the number of cuts you want.

[image]

Comment: @moonboots answered  in the comments while I was typing up my answer, but it is the same.

Comment: I've answered @moonboots thanks for you guys' input. I might just use subdivide