How do I access the vertices of a sphere like this video?
At the time stamp in this video:
https://youtu.be/-XYryP_GU8o?si=x2xfpyYWyuYhVAoV&t=109
They're able to select half of the sphere's vertices to delete it to mirror it. When I try to follow their keystrokes (I'm on Blender 4.2) I don't see the options they do.
When they access Edit mode, they see this:

But when I press Tab to do the same, I see the Cube instead. I know you can do a loop cut, but it doesn't retain its sphericalness


Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

This is obviously not necessarily a beginner tutorial since he goes very quickly over many things, leaves out a lot of explanations etc. because he assumes people watching this video do know basic modeling methods like applying modifiers. The screencast keys also show the applying shortcut before he tabs into Edit Mode.

related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/235822/subdivision-surface-doesnt-show-vertex

Right before he switches to Edit Mode to work on the vertices, he moves the mouse over the Subdivision Surface modifier on the right.
Then he uses the shortcut Ctrl+A which applies the modifier, so it converts the procedural mesh into a real mesh which can be edited.
Here in this screenshot you can see the modifier has disappeared and the screencast keys show the shortcut:


He's also selected xray mode with Alt-Z so all the vertices will be selected when it's box-selected otherwise the vertices on the  back of the model won't be selected for deletion.

@JohnEason One question at a time  In the first screenshot in the question "When they access Edit mode, they see this" it doesn't look like X-ray mode either. Actually they are switching around a lot with no mentioning of it, as I said in the comment under the question, probably not the easiest to follow tutorial for beginners.

I know. That's why I mentioned xray mode. - It shows up on the screencast key combination on your image (Alt-Z), but 'Fake Name's images are in solid view.

@JohnEason I guess 'Fake Name' might even have found out what Alt-Z does since checking the shortcuts from the screencast keys is mentioned in the question. The problem is Ctrl+A is there too, but done in the viewport it brings up a context menu, and I guess the OP just didn't notice that this shortcut was used while hovering the mouse over the modifier panel.

Ah well... Since he's not commented to your answer although he's accepted it as correct I guess we'll never know!
